# How to design an accurate (1 μV error) meter

Tags: voltage-measurement, low-voltage, accuracy

I want to design an accurate LV meter.

The range is from 2.5mV to 50mV both AC, with a 5uV accuracy. This comes from a shunt resistor that is connected to AC main (230V AC). Hence it will go below 0V. In terms of the grounding, it will be separated due to mains voltage. The sampling will be done by a microcontroller

This should then be displayed on a basic 16x2 LCD display.

[image]

My high-level thought process is shown in the above block diagram.

My questions:

1. I was thinking of amplifying the incoming input to 0 to 5 V, which is then fed into an ADC. Is this the best approach in order to achieve the 1 μV accuracy?
2. Should I remove the amplifier and rather just find an ADC that will have the accuracy required?

Comment: 1μV accuracy over a 100mV range is \$\frac{1μV}{100mV} = 10ppm = 0.001\%\$. That's 10 times better than a really expensive multimeter, capable of 0.01% accuracy. It would require ridiculously low noise amplifier, ADC and power supply, and a reference exact to a similar order. Without extremely precise and expensive gear, I doubt you'll be able to get much better than 100μV accuracy.

Comment: @SimonFitch what's ppm? Are there any reference designs that will assist with even the 100uV accuracy?

Comment: PPM = parts-per-million. It's like percent (per 100), but counts millionths instead of hundredths. \$1ppm = \frac{1}{10^6}=0.0001\%\$.

Comment: To be able to suggest any kind of solution, we need to know everything there is to know about the source of 2mV to 100mV. The source, its impedance, its frequency and shape. You can tell us all this by amending your question.

Comment: @SimonFitch, Sorry, I will add it in the post, but the frequency is 50Hz, it's a sine wave, the source is from function generator.

Comment: Is the function generator isolated from the rest of the system, or does it share a common ground? Does the sinusoidal voltage oscillate above and below 0V with respect to your ADC and microcontroller, or is it offset at all?

Comment: Also, are you able to sample the sinusoid, and perform all calculations in software, or must the analogue circuitry also rectify and capture the signal's peaks?

Comment: And if you could build this, how would you plan on calibrating it? Just for reference, that's about double the accuracy of the AC range of a $15,000 multimeter you're asking for. Do you actually mean resolution? And what kind of function generator has that kind of stability?

Comment: You are requesting a resolution of 1 in 100,000 which would require an ADC resolution of 18-bits. In addition to the other questions how would you set the gain of your amplifier and maintain 10 ppm accuracy / stability?

Comment: @SimonFitch I just got a bit more background on this. Again I will update the post. So the range is actually from 2.5mV to 50mV both AC, with a 5uV accuracy. This comes from a shunt resistor that is connected to AC main (220V AC). Hence it will go below 0V. In terms of the grounding it will be separated due to mains voltage. The sampling will be done by a microcontroller

Comment: Wow, you just added the need for isolation too. This one's beyond me already, so I'll back off, I think. I also think whoever is asking you for this doesn't know how complicated the task is.

Comment: A **lock-in amplifier** can do this in principle. You might be able to use the same techniques (using microcontroller software). However, separating the function generator signal from ambient power-line signal noise will be a challenge, especially if your signal is close to line frequency. Perhaps @greybeard is thinking along the same lines.

Comment: @greybeard No I will not. This is the updated spec: So the range is actually from 2.5mV to 50mV both AC, with a 5uV accuracy. This comes from a shunt resistor that is connected to AC main (220V AC). Hence it will go below 0V. In terms of the grounding, it will be separated due to mains voltage. The sampling will be done by a microcontroller

Comment: @greybeard I have edited the question. No, the AC mains will be the actual mains voltage coming out of the wall socket.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your question and the comments, your design specs are:

- 50 mV AC amplitude, max.
- 2.5 mV AC amplitude, min.
- 5 uV resolution on FSR 100 mV PtP
- 50/60 Hz sinosoidal
- Isolation is required
- Source-Impedance unknown but lowisch (mains current shunt)
- **EDIT: Source is a Func-Gend of unknown spec/makes**
- No specification regarding drift (neither long nor short term) or initial accuracy
- No SNR specification
- No sample frequency given

**(1) Comparison to existing products**

- [Fluke 8558](https://eu.flukecal.com/de/products/electrical-calibration/bench-multimeters/8-5-stelliges-multimeter-8558a) "80 μV/V (95 %), 103 µV/V (99 %), 1 Year"
- [Keysight 3458A](https://www.keysight.com/de/de/assets/7018-06796/data-sheets/5965-4971.pdf) "With 100 ppm absolute accuracy for 45 Hz to 1 kHz"
- [Transmille 8104](https://transmillecalibration.com/8000-series-precision-multimeters/)  "(AC Voltage) Best 1 Year Total Accuracy +-0.015%"

**(2) Your specs call for**

```
5 uV/100 mV = 50 ppm = 0.005%
```

**EDIT** Your comments state 50mV FSR (Assuming 25mV AC Amplitude)

```
5 uV/50 mV = 100 ppm = 0.01%
```

50 ppm guaranteed means designing for "around 20 ppm (NOTE: intuitive, not based on facts or experience)" (to account for noise, tolerances, drift, and so many others).

**(3) The elephant in the room**

Can you/your organisation achieve the same as Fluke/Keysight/Others try to perfect since 50+ years within your budget and timetable?

**(4) Alternatives**

It seems as if you wanted to measure AC currents really precisely.

There are options:

- [AC/DC CURRENT SENSOR CT6877](https://www.hioki.com/euro-en/products/current-probes/high-precision/id_6736) I don't know if this fits your requirements. But you will still need a pretty-$ DMM.
- **EDIT as source is not AC-Mains** You won't need a transformer/shunt. Just wire the Func-Gen/DMM directly.

**(5) More abstract (opinion):**

Money can solve these problems.

**Solutions exist. And they are rare for a reason.**

If you have never heard of them/can't judge the price-point intuitively - You won't be able to purchase them with a somewhat high certainty!

Stackoverflow can't solve these problems.

There are companies based around these kinds of measurement tasks. The equipment is extremely specialized and not as simple to operate (correctly) as: Just plug your 2$ leads into the devices and look what the screen says.

Not to talk about designing such a device as a community effort within a community budget and a realistic timetable.

Comment: (Add an order-of-magnitude *purchase resistance* to each *existing product*?) `5uV/100mV` is a mix of question&comment; comment is 5 μV/50 mV or .1‰.

Comment: @greybeard Only an single order these days? :)

Comment: @greybeard Added an Edit. Thank you!